# jQuery remove from multiple root nodes

Tags: jquery

I have the following problem

i create a jquery multinode object and i want to remove one of the node by a jquery selector

```
var o = $("<tr class=items /><tr class=details />");
o.find(".details").remove(); // doesn't work
var outer = $("<div />"); // try to wrap with an outer
outer.append(o);
outer.find(".details").remove(); //removes only from outer
```

thanks for help

Comment: use "" with class. It should looks like class=""

Comment: `find()` looks only among *nested* elements. `filter()` could help you, but I cannot get `remove()` worked for it though :-)

Comment: you havent added o to anything yet, remove will remove only elements from the dom

Comment: @debianek: it wouldn't change anything

Comment: @zerkms that is my comment not solution :)

Comment: try    $("tr.items .details").remove();

Comment: @xFortyFourx: `.details` is not nested to `tr`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I did not notice that. What exactly is your "outer" object ? Would be better if you provide your HTML, and be a little more clear about your requirement.

Comment: the outer element was just a try to remove the node i don't need the outer i just need the o with then removed node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use jQuery's DOM manipulation functions on jQuery Objects. You can either write your own function to do so by extending jQuery or use default Javascript arrays and use inArray to extract your value.

Comment: Right now it is possible. I can create a jQuery object with custom html and manipulate it without attaching it to the dom. So remove *does* work on jQuery objects. Problem is that jQuery is poor in handling multiple root elements. Obviously this has not changed in 9 (!!!) years. Workaround is to use a simple div as a root element.